# Select the Jquery HTML appended data via Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

im having hard time finding the data append by Jquery.
The append system works as following:
getdatafromAjaxRequest->forLoop{appendData}

In the data there are a "menu button"(the  tag) with a HTML onclick attr, this attr call a function to show the dropdown menu.

the HTML appers as expected.
everything works fine. so, the problem is on trying to access the new appended data.

**The AJAX function**

This function is the one which load the Page with the requested info

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: `action/php/engine/Order.eng.php`,
    data: {
        Submit: '',
        Case:   'getOrder',
        Order_status: 3
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var responseArr = JSON.parse(response);
        if (responseArr.status == 1) {

            toogleOrders();
            $('.orderRowContainer').empty();

            for (let i = 0; i < responseArr.payload.length; i++) {
                var ordInfo = responseArr.payload[i].ord_info; // to skip indeixng
                var cusInfo = responseArr.payload[i].cus_info; //to skip indexing
                

                var preisGes = 0;

                for (let x = 0; x < ordInfo.orderItems.payload.length; x++) {
                    preisGes = preisGes + parseInt(ordInfo.orderItems.payload[x].price);
                }
                
                $(".orderRowContainer").append(`
                <div class="orderRow">
                    <div class="orderRow-id" >#${ordInfo.ord_id}</div>
                    <div class="orderRow-text"  ><p>${cusInfo.cus_name}<br/><small>${ordInfo.ord_date} : ${ordInfo.ord_deadline}</small></p></div>
                    <div class="orderRow-cost"  >${preisGes} EUR</div>
                    <div class="orderRow-status ${getStatusColor(ordInfo.ord_status)}"><i style="cursor: pointer;" class="fas fa-chevron-circle-down"></i></div>
                    <div class="orderDropdownMenu" name="dropdown[${i}]">
                        <ul>
                            <li onclick="giveOrder(${ordInfo.ord_id})">Auftrag Abschlisen</li>
                            <li onclick="setKvaS(${ordInfo.ord_id})">Kostenvoranschlag erstellen</li>
                            <li onclick="redirect(${ordInfo.ord_id})">Auftrag Info</li>
                            <li onclick="cancelOrder(${ordInfo.ord_id})">Auftrag Stonierern</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `);
            }
            
           

            

        } else {
            // Show Error on reporter
            miniMsg(responseArr.status, responseArr.msg);
            console.log(responseArr.payload);
        }
        

    }
});
```

HTML which loaded in the Page:

```
<div class="orderRow">
     <div class="orderRow-id"    >#872</div>
     <div class="orderRow-text"  ><p>Name<br/><small>03.11.2020 : 07.11.2020</small></p></div>
     <div class="orderRow-cost"  >70.00 EUR</div>
     <div class="orderRow-status">
         <i style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="showDropMenu(1)" class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
     </div>
     <div class="orderDropdownMenu" name="dropdown[1]">
         <ul>
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
             <li>3</li>
             <li>4</li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Jquery Function to show the `orderDropdownMenu`**

this function gets the dropdown menu id and chang it's display setting to block( show() )

```
var dropMenuIsOpen = 0;

function showDropMenu(id) {
    if (dropMenuIsOpen == 0) {
        var requestedMenuId = $(`[name = "dropdown[${id}]" ]`);
        requestedMenuId.slideToggle("slow");
        dropMenuIsOpen = 1;
    } else {
        //Hide all dropdown menus
        $(".orderDropdownMenu").slideUp("slow");
        dropMenuIsOpen = 0;
    }
    
}
```

**Summary:**

Im looking for a way to edit the new appended data.

i saw in other question that i have to add the data to `$(document)`, that didnt help also.

Comment: I am not seeing `onclick="showDropMenu..` in your appended code .

Comment: @Swati, Well this is the result of late night coding. Thank you man. this solved my problem :)